# EmberJS simpleauth with devise authorizer not sending token header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I can't figure out how to get `ember-simple-auth` with `ember-simple-auth-devise` authorizer (version `0.7.2`) to append the token header to my backend requests.

Here is how my `config/environment.js` looks:

```
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'frontend-app',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {}
    },

    APP: {},

    'simple-auth': {
      authenticationRoute: 'sign-in',
      authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;

    ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
      'font-src': "'self' http://fonts.gstatic.com",
      'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com",
      'connect-src': "'self' http://localhost:3000",
    };

    ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
      serverTokenEndpoint: "//localhost:3000/users/sign_in"
    };

    ENV.apiHost = "http://localhost:3000";
  }
```

I was able to get authentication working, I get a session object in my application. Here are the headers from a successful exchange with the session endpoint:

```
POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 63
Accept: application/json, text/javascript
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:4200/sign-in
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And the server responds with this session object:

```
{"user_token":"eo2xxzYsQ6UifMKvoLMF","user_id":3,"user_email":"snip@snip.com","user_first_name":"Xavier","user_last_name":"Lange"}
```

But all subsequent requests don't set the header:

```
GET /api/reports?user_id=3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:4200/reports
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
If-None-Match: W/"8e1b98de900ac194a0bc3ef6e9dc7459"
```

Where I should expect

```
Authorization: Token token="<token>", email="<email>"
```

to be in the headers sent to the backend. But it's not happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was solved by checking the `crossOriginWhitelist` in development:

```
  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;

    ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
      'font-src': "'self' http://fonts.gstatic.com",
      'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com",
      'connect-src': "'self' http://localhost:3000",
    };

    ENV['simple-auth']['crossOriginWhitelist'] = ['http://localhost:3000'];
    ENV['simple-auth-devise']['serverTokenEndpoint'] = "//localhost:3000/users/sign_in"

    ENV.apiHost = "http://localhost:3000";
  }
```

Then I had to change `simple-auth-devise` to use `email` as the identification property (rails was having a hardtime parsing the Authorization header with `authenticate_with_http_token`:

```
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-app',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    },

    'simple-auth': {
      authenticationRoute: 'sign-in',
      authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
    },

    'simple-auth-devise': {
      identificationAttributeName: 'email'
    }
  };
```

And my session serializer had to sync up with that attribute name:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, only: [:create]

  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        data = {
          token: self.resource.authentication_token,
          user_id: self.resource.id,
          email: self.resource.email,
          user_first_name: self.resource.first_name,
          user_last_name: self.resource.last_name
        }
        render json: data, status: 201
      end
    end
  end
end
```